# How to merge specific axes without ambuigity with numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

Basically I want to reshape tensors represented by numpy.ndarray.

For example, I want to do something like this (latex notation)

A_{i,j,k,l,m,n,p} -> A_{i,jk,lm,np}

or

A_{i,j,k,l,m,n,p} -> A_{ij,k,l,m,np}

where A is an ndarray. i,j,k,... denotes the original axes.

so the new axis 2 becomes the "flattened" version of axis 2 and 3, etc. If I simply use numpy.reshape, I don't think it knows what axes I want to merge, so it seems ambiguous and error prone.

Is there any neat way of doing this rather than creating another ndarray manually?

Comment: You may find the new [einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) command useful

Comment: einsum is a very useful function but I didn't see how I can use it in my case. Could you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 4):

Using `reshape` is never ambiguous. It doesn't change the memory-layout of the data.

Indexing is always done using the strides determined by the shape.
The right-most axis has stride 1, while the axes to the left have strides given by the product of the sizes to their right.

That means for you: as long as you collect neighboring axes, it will do the "right" thing.

Comment: So does it mean I have to stick to C standard (or Fortran standard). Because I'm using einsum to build these tensors, the default option for memory is K("try to keep the memory structure unchanged"), which means indices in front may have smaller strides (according to my understanding). In this case, does what you said still hold?